# How to convert the DVD .VOB collection to MPEG without re-encoding (and quality loss)?

Tags: conversion, mpeg, dvd, lossless

How to convert the DVD .VOB collection to MPEG without re-encoding (and quality loss)? The .MPEG files are what DVD format is built upon, the singular files are easy to handle, and overall, can be manipulated and played more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way, and you'll need the following software,

1. [BadgerIT VOB2MPG (with custom installation instructions for Windows 10)](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/376694-Instructions-for-Running-on-Windows-10)
2. [IfoEdit](https://www.ifoedit.com/%5D) (v0.971 Public, see [checksums](https://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/ifoedit-exe)) - For "Advanced" guide only.

Depending on what you have/want, you may need one of the following sets of instructions,

#### Basic - Convert the full DVD to .MPEG

With this method, you'll get the full DVD copy as a .MPEG file

1. Get to the DVD files

   - If you have a physical DVD, insert it in the drive. (optional) To increase future performance, copy all files to the local hard-drive
   - If you have a DVD image, either extract it or mount it.
   - If you have a raw DVD rip, just proceed with it
2. Open BadgerIT VOB2MPG, navigate to the DVD files directory, and select the `VIDEO_TS.IFO` file.
   *Note*: If you have the .VOB files but not `VIDEO_TS.IFO`, you'll need to follow the second (Advanced) guide below.
3. In BadgerIT VOB2MPG, ensure

   - All necessary titles (if multiple) are selected
   - Correct audio-stream is selected (if you want multiple, you can re-extract multiple times)
   - The output folder is correct
     and click "Start Extraction" (the large "DVD" icon in the top-right corner)

- *Note 1*: You cannot edit the output filename in the software, and that's fine, you can change it later.
- *Note 2*: If you want to select individual chapters, you'll need to follow the "Advanced" guide below.

#### Advanced - Remove ads, select chapters, or extract a few chapters only.

This method is useful if you only want to convert without re-encoding one, few, or most (but not all) .VOB files,

1. Get to the DVD files (like in the basic instructions)
2. Identify the list of the .VOB files you want/need, and copy it to another (empty) folder. For example,

   - If you only want to extract one .VOB file, this is what you'll need to copy.
   - If you only want to extract some of the .VOB files, these are what you'll need to copy
   - If you want to remove ads, you'll need all .VOB files *except* the .VOB files containing the ads

   **Important note**: You are identifying the list of the .VOB files that will be converted to **a single** MPEG file. If you want to convert multiple .VOB files into the single MPEG files, you'll need to redo this set of instructions multiple times.
3. Now make sure you copy the identified files in another folder. I.e. that the copying process is complete.

   *Note 1*: You only need to copy the .VOB files, nothing else.

   *Note 2*: Unless you know what you are going (changing order of video), do NOT rename any files, before or after the copying.
4. Open IfoEdit, click the button at the bottom, titled "Create IFOs"

   I. In "Output Stream > 1st VOB of Title-Set", select the first .VOB file.

   II. In "Output Stream", ensure "Same as Source" is **Checked**
5. Finally, check "OK" and wait. .VOB files will be read, but not edited. If you feel paranoid, you can always verify hash, for example with [HashMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html)
6. Now proceed with the steps from the "Basic" guide (specifically from step 2), by selecting the newly made folder in VOB2MPG

#### Extras - But I need to cut my MPG even further!

Luckily, frame-perfect cutting .MPG files without re-encoding and quality loss [is also possible](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/34826)

---

I hope this guide helps someone in the future.